# Is it safe to park a motorbike on the street at night Spain?

Tags: safety, spain, motorcycles

To be quick: Can I leave my motorcycle (mine in a brend new Triumph tiger 800) unattended in the street at night in Spain?

Or is it better to hide it in a garage ? Is a big-lock recommended ?

This is mainly about the countryside, but I will also cross some medium cities. I am planing to cross all Spain from Basque country down to Andalusia. (if it is too complicated to detail, then just give worst case).

My question can seems quite un-usual, but I am from Switzerland and I left my motorcycle in the streets with only the steering locked and its safe to do so. What about Spain ?

Comment: Antoine - Spain is a big country. In some areas this would be safe, in others very unsafe. I don't think the question can be answered well, as it currently stands - although I would suggest you should consider it generally a bit more likely to be stolen in Spain than Switzerland.

Comment: This is *way* too broad. Only you can be the judge of this, and very often parking motorbikes on the streets at night is a gamble.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. It's not the same a rural area or a city. Not the same the north or the south. Not the same if your motorbike is very attractive or not.

In my experience, you won't have any problem leaving your motorbike alone at night, but any safety measure will be welcomed. I've gone through all Spain (except Galicia) with my ATV without any safety measure except a typical padlock to dissuade oportunist thieves and nothing happened. The most common "problem" is to find that the bike you parked in the middle of the town square is the children attraction of the day.